# Signalr load testing in JMeter

Tags: websocket, jmeter, signalr, long-polling

I'm trying to do JMeter script for an application with Signalr protocol.
I'm able to identify connection-token, bearer-token, connection-id and co relate with request using long polling transport and  receive message, but after third polling I could not receive the correct response, i'm getting response but not the expected and full response.

Could you please help me what could be the issue here?

[image: LongPoll_Request]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid no one will be able to help without seeing at least:

1. Anticipated response
2. Actual response
3. Reference requests sequence from i.e. real browser captured with a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler)
4. The same as point 3 but for JMeter instead of the real browser.

Basically you need to execute points 3 and 4 and compare the generated network requests - they must be the same apart from the dynamic parameters (tokens, connection-id, etc.). Given requests are the same - you should be getting the same responses.

Another option is using [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) in order to continue polling unless response matches your expectation.

Comment: Thank you Dmitri, I tried executing the requests from parallel controller since all these request are sent parallel ( which i found using fiddler) and I'm able to get the expected response.

Comment: Hi Mani, can you please help me here, how did you do that ?